# Как прочитать csv файл в dataframe pandas размером 4GB?

Tags: python, numpy, csv

Я попробовала библиотеку modis - она не работает,
Dusk - читает файл, но в каких то точках и object
Через chunk я попыталась найти правильный код, но ни один не работает :(
Мне нужны все строчки так как нужно построить ML модель. Буду применять numpy
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну вообще чанками должно работать. Что за модель у вас? И нужны ли вам все поля? Можно попробовать сразу ограничить число читаемых полей до необходимого минимума и задать dtypes покомпактнее, настолько, чтобы данные влезали без запаса. Это реально экономит место, но нужно понимать, что вы вообще делаете. Хотя бы пример данных покажите. И что за модель вы строите.

Comment: И обычно для модели гораздо меньше данных хватает. А если вам реально столько нужно обрабатывать, то требуйте себе соответствующие мощности под задачу - память и всё прочее. )

Comment: @CrazyElf я только планирую строить, данные я еще не смогла открыть из-за размера. Я даже не могу просмотреть info()

Comment: @CrazyElf вы можете пожалуйста поделиться примером работающего кода с chunks, или ссылку на статью, если вы не против

Comment: А вручную для начала открыть хоть в FAR файл да посмотреть что там вообще )

Comment: А вот это читали https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642951/python-using-pandas-structures-with-large-csviterate-and-chunksize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14262433/large-data-work-flows-using-pandas/14268804#14268804

Comment: Если так и не получится - приведите ваш код с чанками, будем разбираться.

Comment: Можете привести __небольшой__ (3-5 строк) пример данных? Какую ML модель вы хотите использовать?